# Convert Tuple into Foldable

Tags: haskell, fold, haskell-lens, foldable

Is there a way to derive `Foldable` from `Tuple`?
At least when the tuple is homogeneous?

For example let's say I have `(1,2,3)` and I want to `reverse` it or to transform it into `[1,2,3]` and similar things.

I've tried to do something like

```
over each (\x -> 4 -x) (1,2,3) -- lol
```

but I need a sort of equivalent of fold with lens...

and actually I see that I can do

```
 foldr1Of each (\a x -> a+x) (1,2,3)
```

but I would need instead

```
 foldr1Of each (\a x -> a:x) (1,2,3)
```

which doesn't compile

Comment: In order to convert it to a list, you should use `foldrOf each (:) [] (1,2,3)`, since your initial accumulator is the empty list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks! that's what I was looking for

Comment: "toListOf each" should do the trick, also see the infix alias ^..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I would need instead
>
> ```
> foldr1Of each (\a x -> a:x) (1,2,3)
> ```
>
> which doesn't compile

The reason why this does not compile is because `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` expects a list as second argument, but with `foldr1Of`, you provide it the *last* element of your fold, which is here a number.

You can solve it by using [**`foldrOf :: Getting (Endo r) s a -> (a -> r -> r) -> r -> s -> r`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#v:foldrOf) instead:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> foldrOf each (:) [] (1,2,3)
[1,2,3]
```

Here we thus pass `[]` as the "initial accumulator".

We can thus convert several several "containers" to lists with:

```
toList :: Each s s a a => s -> [a]
toList = foldrOf each (:) []
```

For example:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> toList (1,2)
[1,2]
Prelude Control.Lens> toList (1,2,3)
[1,2,3]
Prelude Control.Lens> toList (1,2,3,4)
[1,2,3,4]
Prelude Control.Lens> toList [1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
Prelude Control.Lens> toList Nothing
[]
Prelude Control.Lens> toList (Just 2)
[2]
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Willem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55990702/2751851), it is worth noting that [`Control.Lens.Fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html) offers analogues for pretty much everything in `Data.Foldable`. That includes `toList`, which becomes [`toListOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:toListOf):

```
GHCi> toListOf each (1,2,3)
[1,2,3]
```